# Why the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{1}{(x-i)^2} \frac{1}{(x+i)^2}$ is not zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

This might be silly but I am almost pulling my hair.

Why the following integral (along the real axis) is not zero:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{1}{(x-i)^2} \frac{1}{(x+i)^2}$$

The integral has no residues and can be completed by a semicircle either in the upper complex plane or the lower complex plane. According to the residue theorem, it should be zero. (Mathematica says it's $\pi/2$)

What's wrong with my logic here?

**Edit:**
I was somehow given the wrong impression that high-order poles does not contribute to the residue.

Comment: So you integrate the real valued, positive function $1/(x^2+1)^2$, which on the interval $[-1,1]$ is $\ge 1/4$ and expect still a zero value? Which is the question exactly, which are the residues in $\pm i$?

Comment: It equals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}$ which is patently positive.

Comment: Well, since the integrand is positive for all $x$, it is kind of hard to swallow your claim that the integral has value 0.

Comment: You say that there are no residues, but the integrand has double poles at $\pm i$ and the residues at each of these are nonzero.

Comment: I understand that it should not be zero. But there's not residue anywhere. A residue should look like $1/(z-\alpha)$, not $1/(z-\alpha)^2$. No?

Comment: You seemed to be muddled about what a residue is. It's the coefficient of $1/(z-a)$ in the Laurent series at $z=a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, but the residue theorem *does* give a nonzero value. There are second-order poles at $\pm i$, and the integrand's residue [at such a pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) is $$\lim_{x\to\pm i}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(x\pm i)^2}=\frac{-2}{(\pm 2i)^3}=\mp\frac{i}{4}.$$As I think your only mistake was in misunderstanding how higher-order poles provide residues, I'll leave it to you to understand why we can calculate the integral from the pole at $i$ alone, viz.$$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}=2\pi i\times\frac{-i}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2},$$just as your software said. (It can also be proven with $x=\tan t$.)

Edit: let me motivate the way higher-order poles work. Suppose $f(c)$ is neither $0$ nor infinite. Then $$\oint\frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^n}dz=\oint\frac{f^{n-1}(c)}{(n-1)!(z-c)}dz=2\pi i\cdot\lim_{z\to c}\frac{f^{n-1}(z)}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: Possibly remove the sentence "only poles at $i$ contribute to the integral"? We can do this in the lower complex plane as well, where $-i$ will contribute.

Comment: @ChongWang Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the residue theorem, it should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as it is. Let $\gamma(R)$ be the union of the segment from $-R$ to $R$ and the arc $Re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, counter-clockwise oriented.  Due to the ML lemma we have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2} = \lim_{R\to +\infty}\oint_{\gamma(R)}\frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^2}=2\pi i\cdot\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i}\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2} $$
(notice that the pole at $-i$ is not enclosed by $\gamma(R)$) and by partial fraction decomposition
$$ \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\left[\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{x-i}-\frac{1}{x+i}\right)\right]^2=\frac{-1/4}{(x-i)^2}+\frac{-i/4}{(x-i)}+\frac{i/4}{(x+i)}+\frac{-1/4}{(x+i)^2} $$
so
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^2}=2\pi i\cdot(-i/4)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
The real-analytic approach is even simpler: since for any $A>0$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{A+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{A}}$, by differentiating both sides with respect to $A$ we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(A+x^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2A\sqrt{A}}$ and it is enough to evaluate at $A=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, i will compute explicitly the residue in $i$ by computing the Laurent expansion, we have using $h=x-i$
$$
\begin{aligned}
(x-i)^{-2}\frac 1{(x+i)^2}
&=
h^{-2}\frac 1{(2i+h)^2}
=
h^{-2}\frac 1{4i^2}\frac 1{(1-\frac {ih}2)^2}
\\
&=
-\frac 14h^{-2}
\left(
1
+2\left(\frac{ih}2\right)
+3\left(\frac{ih}2\right)^2
+\dots\right)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the residue in $i$ is $-i/4$.

Applying the residue theorem on that $D$-rotated contour, we get passing to the limit the value $2\pi i\cdot\left(-\frac i4\right)=\frac \pi 2$, which is matching the computer prediction:

```
sage: var( 'x' );
sage: f = 1/(x^2+1)^2
sage: integral( f, x, -oo, +oo )
1/2*pi
sage: f.residue( x==i )
-1/4*I
sage: 2*pi*i * f.residue( x==i )
1/2*pi
```

Comment: I hope this argument (Laurent expansion) makes clear why the presence of $(x-i)^2$ in the denominator still contributes to a residual value, it is because "the rest" (factor) still has its own contribution in its Taylor expansion, here in degree one.